# VB.net compare a full string to one containing wildcard characters

Tags: vb.net

I have a method that takes 2 string arguments. One that contains a normal string and one that contains a string with one or more wildcard characters. I've tried the following code:

```
Private Function DoesMatchWildcardString(ByVal fullString As String, ByVal wildcardString As String) As Boolean
    Dim stringParts() As String
    Dim matches As Boolean = True

    stringParts = wildcardString.Split("*")

    For Each str As String In stringParts
        If fullString.Contains(str) = False Then
            matches = False
        End If
    Next

    Return matches

End Function
```

The I realized that it won't work properly. If I have ABCD as a normal and A*CD as my wildcard string the match will work even if my normal string was CDAB, which is not what I want.

Any ideas??

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What are possible wildcard characters? Are you talking about just `*`, or more full regex-like `*`, `+`, `?`, `.`, etc. ?

Comment: Right now I'm only working with *

Comment: Why don't you test each part of the string one at a time? So split the wildcard string A*CD into two. Test A against the first character of the normal string. Then test CD against the third and fourth characters of the normal string.

Comment: In your example, it seems that `*` stands for a single character e.g. `A*CD` - is that true?

Comment: @kaveman - No the * can stand for any number of characters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your approach is interesting but very inefficient even once corrected. An efficient implementation of the wildcard matching algorithm uses an extension of the [**shift-or algorithm**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitap_algorithm) (according to Wikipedia also called “bitap” by some sources, but I’ve never read that myself).

The only change to the conventional shift-or algorithm is in the preprocessing: For each `*` that you encounter in the pattern, enable *all* characters in the alphabet at this position.

If you want to correct your own algorithm, then replace the `Contains` call by `IndexOf`, and supply the position where it should start searching – namely, after the previous match. This will work for most cases, but it will perform a non-greedy search which might fail in some circumstances. An exhaustive search will necessarily backtrack. As I said, that’s inefficient, and the shift-or algorithm doesn’t suffer from this shortcoming.

**But all of this is unnecessary** since VB already provides the necessary operator: **`Like`**

```
If fullString Like wildcardString Then
    ' Yep, matches.
End If
```

---

A note on style:

Always initialise variables when you declare them, do not separate declaration and initialisation needlessly.

That is, write

```
Dim stringParts As String() = wildcardString.Split("*")
' or, with Option Infer On:
Dim stringParts = wildcardString.Split("*")
```

Furthermore, it makes no sense to compare a Boolean with a literal (`If X = False` …). Just write

```
If fullString.Contains(str) Then
```

Comment: I like the style tips. I would add that if all you are doing in a Boolean test is determining which value to set a different Boolean variable, combine them into one e.g. `matches = fullString.Contains(str)`

Answer (score 0):

`"*"` does not represent a single char but any range of chars. When you want to compare two strings I have found that the `if maskedtextbox1.text like maskedtextbox2.text` or `maskedtextbox2.text = maskedtextbox1.text` works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, does this help?

```
Private Function DoesMatchWildcardString(ByVal fullString As String, ByVal wildcardString As String) As Boolean
    Dim count As Integer = 1
    Dim wildchr As String
    Dim fschr As String
    Dim resultstring As String = String.Empty

    Do Until count - 1 = Len(wildcardString)
        wildchr = Mid$(wildcardString, count, 1)
        fschr = Mid$(fullString, count, 1)
        If wildchr = "*" Then ' this one matches any char
            resultstring = resultstring & fschr
        Else
            If wildchr = fschr Then
                resultstring = resultstring & fschr
            End If
        End If
        count = count + 1
    Loop
    Return resultstring = fullString
End Function
```